# ASP.NET: Why can I execute query once only?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET service. Inside it I use the access to SQL Server, i.e. add the DbConnection etc

```
  services.AddScoped<IDbConnection, SqlConnection>(_ => new SqlConnection(sqlcon));
  services.AddScoped<ICRepository, CRepository>();
```

This DbConnection used in the classes which queried a db.

BUT I can execute the query 1st time and it returns the correct items.
If I execute it the 2nd time I receive:
"message": "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."

and really the dbconnection object is empty and not initialized
How to fix it?
That is minimized piece of code

```
 public class CRepository : ICRepository
    {
        private readonly IDbConnection _db;

        public CRepository(IDbConnection db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
//....
        public List<MyAction> GetMyActions()
        {
            var sql = $@"
                SELECT id,name, description from actions;";

            var result = _db.Query<MyAction>(sql).ToList();
            return result;
        }
...
}
```

ANd the first time the _db is initialized but the 2nd one - no.

Comment: DbConnection isn't thread safe. I suggest to declare the service as transient.

Comment: Ok, what about AddSingleton? is it ok too?

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with using a Scoped SqlConnection.  Please post a repro of the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: I have added the code to the start message.

Comment: Singleton is a unique instance for all the application. In your case, one instance of DbConnection in all the application (and in all thread), I strongly advise against. Scoped service is one instance by request. If the request is managed in one thread, in your case is fine but I doubt it in view of the error. Transiend is a new instance everytime and generaly the better choise, but not adapted for all scenarios, like a shared service (ex : cache).

Comment: Do you use Automapper?

Comment: I use Dapper. But I commented these Dapper calls and used usual SqlCommand ExecuteReader and ExecuteScalar - the result the same: 1st time it works each next time the _db is nit initialized.

Comment: Btw, when I changed this             
    //services.AddSingleton<IDbConnection, SqlConnection>(_ => new SqlConnection(sqlcon));
to this 
    services.AddTransient<IDbConnection, SqlConnection>(_ => new SqlConnection(sqlcon));
 
then received the same error: db.ConnectionString is not initialized

Comment: Can you share the related code in the IDbConnection interface and the SqlConnection class?

Comment: These objects are System.Data.IDbConnection and System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

Comment: Hi @ZedZip, have you solved the problem? If not, I create a new application and test your code, everything works well. Can you share the relate code about how to use the ICRepository, and which line of code will show the "db.ConnectionString is not initialized" error?